# How to add click to go to next slide in this touch slider carousel

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile, carousel

Currently the carousel goes from slide to slide through the use of sliding with your finger, but on top of that, I want to add arrows that allow you to go from slide to slide.

Even if the arrows are just part of the logo image, that would be fine for me. Any ideas on how to implement this? Any form of arrows which would allow users to click through the slides rather than dragging would work for me.

```js
/**
* Code by Noé Falque ➡️ noe.im
**/

class Slider {
  constructor(el) {

    this.el = el
    this.container = this.el.querySelector('.slides-container')
    this.slides = this.container.querySelectorAll('.slide')
    this.parallaxes = this.container.querySelectorAll('.parallax')

    this.current = 0;
    this.currentPos
    this.mouseOffset
    this.moving = false

    this.container.style.width = this.slides.length * 100 + '%'
    this.slides[0].classList.add('current')

    let startPos, lastTouchX

    const

      dragStart = (e) => {
        e.stopPropagation()
        if (e.touches) lastTouchX = e.touches[0].clientX
        startPos = e.clientX || lastTouchX
        this.mouseOffset = 0
        this.currentPos = this.container.getBoundingClientRect().left;
        this.moving = true;
        requestAnimationFrame(this.move.bind(this))
      },

      dragEnd = (e) => {
        if (this.moving) {
          const moveX = e.clientX || lastTouchX
          if (moveX < startPos - 100) this.next()
          else if (moveX > startPos + 100) this.prev()
          else this.goTo(this.current)
          this.moving = false
        }
      },

      dragMove = (e) => {
        if (e.touches) lastTouchX = e.touches[0].clientX
        const moveX = e.clientX || lastTouchX
        this.mouseOffset = moveX - startPos
      }

    this.container.addEventListener('mousedown', dragStart)
    this.container.addEventListener('touchstart', dragStart)

    window.addEventListener('mouseup', dragEnd)
    this.container.addEventListener('touchend', dragEnd)

    window.addEventListener('mousemove', dragMove)
    this.container.addEventListener('touchmove', dragMove)

    window.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
      e = e || window.event;
      if (e.keyCode == '39') {// right arrow
        this.next()
      }
      else if (e.keyCode == '37') {// left arrow
        this.prev()
      }
    })

  }

  move() {
    if (this.moving) {
      this.container.style.transform = 'translate3d(' + (this.currentPos + this.mouseOffset) + 'px, 0, 0)'
      this.container.classList.add('moving')
      const slideWidth = this.slides[0].offsetWidth;
      this.slides.forEach(($_slide, i) => {
        const coef = 1 - Math.abs($_slide.getBoundingClientRect().left / slideWidth)
        $_slide.style.opacity = .5 + (coef * .5)
        $_slide.style.transform = 'scale(' + (.9 + coef * .1) + ')'
      })
      this.parallaxes.forEach(($_item, i) => {
        const coef = this.slides[i].getBoundingClientRect().left / slideWidth
        $_item.style.opacity = 1 - Math.abs(coef * 1.8)
        $_item.style.transform = 'translate3d(' + (-coef * 85) + '%, 0, 0)'
      })
      requestAnimationFrame(this.move.bind(this))
    }
  }

  goTo(i) {
    if (i >= 0 && i < this.slides.length) this.current = i
    this.container.classList.remove('moving')
    this.container.style.transform = 'translate3d(' + this.current * -100 / this.slides.length + '%, 0, 0)'

    this.slides.forEach(($_slide, i) => {
      $_slide.classList.remove('current')
      $_slide.removeAttribute('style')
    })
    this.slides[this.current].classList.add('current')
    this.slides[this.current].removeAttribute('style')

    this.parallaxes.forEach(($_item, i) => {
      $_item.removeAttribute('style')
      $_item.style.transform = 'translate3d(' + (i <= this.current ? 85 : -85) + '%, 0, 0)'
    })
    this.slides[this.current].querySelector('.parallax').removeAttribute('style')
  }

  next() {
    this.goTo(this.current + 1)
  }

  prev() {
    this.goTo(this.current - 1)
  }

}

const $sliders = document.querySelectorAll('.slider')
const sliders = []
$sliders.forEach(($slider) => {
  sliders.push(new Slider($slider))
})
```

```css
ul,
body,
p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.slider {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: black;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 55vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slider .slides-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: -webkit-grab;
  cursor: grab;
  transition: transform .5s;
}

.slider:active .slides-container {
  cursor: -webkit-grabbing;
  cursor: grabbing;
}

.slider .slides-container.moving {
  transition: none;
}

.slider .slides-container.moving .slide {
  transition: none;
}

.slider .slides-container.moving .parallax {
  transition: none;
}

.slider .slide {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  opacity: .8;
  transform: scale(.9);
  transform-origin: center;
  transition: transform .5s, opacity .5s;
}

.slider .slide.current {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
}

.slider .slide .parallax {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: transform .5s, opacity .5s;
}

.slider .slide.current .parallax {
  display: flex;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.slider .slide .content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.slider .slide .parallax p {
  position: static;
  text-align: left;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 2.3em;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 77%
}

.slider .slide .parallax img {
  position: static;
  width: 35%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.slider .slide .parallax #TNYT {
  position: static;
  width: 35%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding-top: 15px;
}

.slider .slide .parallax #ESQUIRE {
  position: static;
  width: 40%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: -10px;
}

.slider .slide .parallax #CNET {
  position: static;
  width: 35%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: -10px;
}

.slider .slide:nth-child(6n+2) {
  background: #fff;
}

.slider .slide:nth-child(6n+3) {
  background: #fff;
}

.slider .slide:nth-child(6n+4) {
  background: #fff;
}

.slider .slide:nth-child(6n+5) {
  background: #fff;
}

.slider .slide:nth-child(6n+6) {
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <ul class="slides-container">
    <li class="slide">
      <div class="parallax">
        <div class="content">
          <p class="quote">“By eliminating middlemen and maintaining zero surplus stock,
            Kuze is able to offer its premium products at a more affordable price compared to other bespoke clothing
            brands, while still being Eco-friendly.”</p>
          <img class="logo" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0758/3105/0520/files/GQ.png?v=1700523020" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="slide">
      <div class="parallax">
        <div class="content">
          <p class="quote">“Say goodbye to ill-fitting clothes - no more drooping shoulders,
            rolled-up cuffs, or loose, baggy tops and stretched waists.
            With Kuze, every piece is tailored to fit you perfectly.”</p>
          <img id="TNYT" class="logo" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0758/3105/0520/files/TNYT.png?v=1700523020" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="slide">
      <div class="parallax">
        <div class="content">
          <p class="quote">“Kuze collaborates with leading fashion professionals and academic researchers to develop
            their
            Fit Recognition Engine®, ensuring a precise and personalized fit for every individual.”</p>
          <img id="ESQUIRE" class="logo" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0758/3105/0520/files/Esquire.png?v=1700523020" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="slide">
      <div class="parallax">
        <div class="content">
          <p class="quote">“the ultimate aim at Kuze is to boost the confidence of their customers by providing them
            with
            clothing that not only looks good but also feels great to wear.”</p>
          <img id="CNET" class="logo" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0758/3105/0520/files/CNET.png?v=1700523020" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="slide">
      <div class="parallax">
        <div class="content">
          <p class="quote">“At Kuze, each piece of clothing created is a unique masterpiece, tailored to ensure a
            precise
            fit. From incorporating your initials to meticulous tailoring, they ensure that every product is truly
            one-of-a-kind.”</p>
          <img class="logo" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0758/3105/0520/files/Details.png?v=1700523020" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please add the following code into your html, css, js code and check if that's work,

HTML:

```
<div class="slider">
<div class="arrow arrow-left">&lt;</div>
<div class="arrow arrow-right">&gt;</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.arrow {
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 transform: translateY(-50%);
 font-size: 24px;
 color: white;
 cursor: pointer;
 z-index: 2;
}

.arrow-left {
left: 10px;
 }

.arrow-right {
right: 10px;
}
```

JS:

```
  class Slider {
 // ... existing code ...

 constructor(el) {
  // ... existing code ...

// Add event listeners for arrow buttons
el.querySelector('.arrow-left').addEventListener('click', () => this.prev());
el.querySelector('.arrow-right').addEventListener('click', () => this.next());
 }

 // ... existing code ...
 }
```

Thanks

Comment: Hey thank you, it worked!!!